# How do I start autoIncrement from 0 instead of 1 with Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, primary-key

Please, help. 
I have a table which is uses foreign key values starting from 0. 
When I try to generate entities using hibernate it always starts autoincrement from 1. Is there a way to force it to start from 0?
My hibernate primary key currently set up this way:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
Long id;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that 0 is a good value for a primary key. Because 0 could be interpreted some where as not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'
```

> NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO affects handling of AUTO_INCREMENT columns. Normally, you generate the next sequence number for the column by inserting either NULL or 0 into it. NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO suppresses this behavior for 0 so that only NULL generates the next sequence number.
>
> This mode can be useful if 0 has been stored in a table's AUTO_INCREMENT column. (Storing 0 is not a recommended practice, by the way.)

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero)

[Reference 2](https://serverfault.com/questions/42071/how-to-force-mysql-to-take-0-as-a-valid-auto-increment-value/42074#42074)

Comment: So, only way to make it work is to first set up database this way? I was trying to avoid incrementing the id in the query, but after I've read the comments it seems to be a cheaper option than messing around with database settings

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Simon. 0 is not a good value for a primary key. Also, as far as I know, there will be no way to configure Hibernate to make this bad practice. But if you really want to stick to start with zero, you could remove the autoincrement and make: 

`SELECT MAX(column_name)
FROM table_name;`

And work around it. But in my opinion as a developer, 0 is a good value when working with arrays and so on, but PK's should always start with 1.